# How to display a favicon on Heroku for a plotly-dash app

Tags: heroku, plotly-dash, favicon

I recently deployed my first dash web app on Heroku (yeah!) and everything works like a charm so far. However, although I was able to add a favicon in my local app, the favicon fails to be displayed when deployed on Heroku. I was only able to find solutions for this problem for other frameworks - but not for dash.

In the beginning, I had my `favicon.ico` in an `assets/` folder - which worked for displaying the favicon locally. I then tried moving it to `public/` and to the source directory of my app - but nothing resulted in the display of my favicon on Heroku.

Do you know if or how I have to set any paths / tags to link to my `favicon.ico` in the source code of my dash app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
   brand_href=app.get_asset_url("favicon.ico"),
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it